# onclick inside function fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, onclick

I have 3 inputs and 3 buttons. I would like to set a value by clicking on the button. Everything working fine with the first set. When I set next input, it change the value of all my inputs.

How can I fix that?

```js
$(function() {
  $("input").on("click", function () {
  var here = $(this);
    
    $("div").on("click", "button", function() {
      here.val(this.value);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">

<div>
  <button value="a">a</button>
  <button value="b">b</button>
  <button value="c">c</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you wanting to place the value of the Button, into the last focused INPUT,.

This might help..

```js
$(function() {
  var lastFocus;
  $('body').on('focus','input', function () {
    lastFocus = this;
  });
  $("div").on("click", "button", function() {
    $(lastFocus).val(this.value);    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">

<div>
  <button value="a">a</button>
  <button value="b">b</button>
  <button value="c">c</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't scope click function inside click function , just use two click and global variable ...

```
$(function() {
var here;
  $("input").on("click", function () {
     here = $(this);       
  });
  $("div").on("click", "button", function() {
      here.val(this.value);
  });
});
```

Comment: Just a head's up,  `here` is not a global variable.  It's a local variable scoped to the anonymous function.  Just saying, as global variable's are known as bad, but what you have done here is good, you have created a closure that captures the local var `here`.

Answer (score 1):

is this you want ?

```js
$(function() {
  $("input").on("click", function () {
  var here = $(this);
    
    $("div").on("click", "button", function() {
      here.val(this.value+here.val());
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">

<div>
  <button value="a">a</button>
  <button value="b">b</button>
  <button value="c">c</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Every time you click an input, your creating a new set of delegated events.  eg. if say you click all three inputs, when you click the button it will do your event 3 times, click the inputs again it will do it 6 times etc.  It's a kind of memory leak :)

Answer (score 1):

Why have you used the outer function?

You can add a temporary class to the input, to which you want to change the value.

```
    $("input").on("click", function () {
       $("input").removeClass('addToThis');
       $(this).addClass('addToThis');
    });

    $("div").on("click", "button", function() {
      $(".addToThis").val(this.text());
    });
```

Comment: I think it should be `$(".addToThis")` (starting with a dot) and `$(this).text()` instead of `this.value`. Ex: `$(".addToThis").val($(this).text());`

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution: just put the here variable out the first click listner:

```
$(function() {
  var here;
  $("input").on("click", function () {
    here  = $(this);
    $("div").on("click", "button", function() {
      here.val(this.value);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: A little warning, every time you click an input your creating a new set of delegated events.. As an example place a console.log() inside your button click, click a few inputs and watch your events build up.  Also have a look a snippets instead of plnkr / codepen etc.